# Is there a way to retain boolean value changed inside of an ActionListener once it's been changed inside the ActionListener?

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop, boolean, actionlistener

i'm trying to make a poker game for a school project and im having particular difficulty changing this one variable. My code uses a while loop in the main of my class to handle data coming from the server, and as such data cannot be sent back to the server outside this loop. because of this, I need to change the value of the turnOver boolean variable within the ActionListener so that code in the while loop can be executed accordingly. However, when i try to change it, it's almost as if the value it's changed to is immediately disregarded once the ActionListener code is complete, and as such, the code within the loop never gets executed. The ActionListener is defined within the main.

Is there a way to 'retain' the value that the boolean turnOver is changed to so that i can use it again in the main? I've tried to explain this as best as i can and i will attach my code below (i'm pretty new to all this server/socket based stuff). Thank you for reading.

Relevant code for the actionListener:

```
public class Client {
public static Client bob = new Client();
private static boolean turnOver = false;
public static Table clientTable = new Table();


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("player joining");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    bob.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 8000);
    System.out.println("player joined");
    clientTable.betButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("value of turnOver: " + turnOver);
                Client.this.turnOver = true;
                System.out.println("value of turnOver: " + turnOver);
                System.out.println("bet button clicked");
            }

            catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Relevant code for the while loop within the same main method:

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("value of turnOver before check " + turnOver);

        if (turnOver == true) {
            System.out.println("reached turn over status");
            [REST OF METHOD]
        }
```

With this current implementation, i never see the message "reached turn over status", and from that i assume that the value of turnOver is never true, even though i set it to be so in the ActionListener. How may i rectify this? Thank you.

Comment: My first thought is - don't it this way, but that's a long and complicated answer.  My second thought is to make use of `AtomicBoolean` to allow the value to be shared correctly between the threads, assuming you're using threads, which would cause a hole bag of other issues otherwise

Comment: I cant really change it at this point, due date is coming up fast and there isnt enough time. How would i go about using AtomicBoolean? I tried changing my boolean values to AtomicBoolean and changing the appropriate checks by using the appropriate methods but it didnt seem to change anything.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're using the variables. Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it takes out the guess work and generally results in better answers

Comment: *"there isnt enough time"* You need better time-management skills more than help from people on stack overflow. I for one would prefer to help people who can implement suggestions because they *have* the time.